# Problems running FoxPro on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: dll, foxpro

I am trying to support a really old system that I did not build.  I have Foxpro that runs fine on a PC with Windows XP Pro, but when I use the same program on a PC with Windows 7 Pro, it gives the error "missing DLL"

Comment: Does it give the name of the missing DLL?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of FoxPro - FoxPro for DOS, FoxPro for Windows, one of the versions of Visual FoxPro?

I'm guessing the latter i.e. Visual FoxPro. At a guess you don't have the run-time libraries for whatever version of Visual FoxPro was used installed on the Windows 7 PC. You can get various runtime installers [here.](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/FoxPro/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=125)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing a VFP Runtime on this PC. The below link allows you to download VFP 6, 7, 8 and 9 runtimes. Hopefully the app that you are supporting is one of these versions. Just download the required version and install. Or install them all.

[VFP Runtimes](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/FoxPro/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=125)

Answer (score 0):

That is common VFP problem, and there is easy solution :

You need to instal missing runtime files, and hole files you can find on your instalation CD, in WCU folder. Try ti start bootstrap.msi(setup)...

That solved problem for me!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Visual FoxPro runtime installers here:

http://vfpx.codeplex.com/releases/view/194354

Versions available for downlaod are:

```
VFP6 SP5
VFP7 SP1
VFP8 SP1
VFP9 SP2
```